# Iframe onload event only after an anchor onclick

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="iframe_a" onload="alert('Thanks for the visit!');"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="iframe_a">Go!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to see the alert message after clicking on the link and when the iframe finishes loading. But now it appears on the initial page load, too. How can I achieve it so it works in IE8+?

Just came up with a simple solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe_a" name="iframe_a" onload="if(this.className=='active'){alert('Thanks for the visit!');};"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="iframe_a" onclick="document.getElementById('iframe_a').className='active';">Go!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no (sane) way to prevent onload of an iframe when it's in the DOM. Adding onload to iframe just before you're loading it should fix your issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="myIframe" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#myIframe').load(function() {alert('Thanks for the visit!');}); $('#myIframe').attr('src','http://www.example.com/')">Go!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now it's better... jQuery (or some other framework) should take care of browser differences

Comment: I prefer to use pure JavaScript for such a simple problem. However, now it works across different browsers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEvent = (function() {
                var evnt = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
                    pre = evnt === "attachEvent" ? "on" : "";

                return function (ele, evnt, func, bub) {
                    ele[evnt](pre + evnt, func, bub);
                }
            }());
            addEvent(window, "load", function() {
                addEvent(document.getElementById("myIframe"), "load", function() {
                    alert("Loaded!");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="myIframe" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
        <a href="..." target="iframe_a">GO!</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the iframe src not from the same domain as the above page? If they aren't then this might be blocked due to XSS concerns

Comment: I meant after the ahref is clicked :)

Comment: I tried different URLs including the same domain, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this way, works in IE 8:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="iframe_a" onclick="alert('Thanks for the visit!');">Go!</a>
```

Comment: THe problem here is that he wants the iframe's onload event to trigger the alert, not the onclick of the anchor

Comment: Using your code the alert message appears as soon as I click on the link. But it should appear when the iframe finishes loading and that's why I used the onload event.

Comment: Gimme a few mins. :) Okay I give up. No better answer from my side.

Answer (score 0):

This one is funny but it does what you need (in pure JavaScript lol):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
var a = 0;
function doIt() {
if(++a == 1) return;
alert('Thanks for the visit!');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="iframe_a" onload="doIt()"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="iframe_a">Go!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work if we change the way to attach the event to the iframe element:[example](http://jsfiddle.net/H3sN3/)

Comment: IE-what? LOL! It's a dead browser.

Comment: neither it works in IE7, so you could probably specify browser requirements in the question?

Comment: You're right. Just edited the question and appreciate your time and help! :)

Comment: Just came up with a solution. I'd be happy to get your review.